# Convert Swing application to Java EE

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I am a java developer and I develop applications in Swing. I use NetBeans and Eclipse as IDEs.

I want to create the same web application in Java EE. I know the concept of Java EE - JSP, taglib and the hibernate framework. But I'm not able to design a web application.

Can anyone help me what I need to learn to start web application design: which IDE, which framework?

Comment: FYI: J2EE died May 2006.It's since then Java EE. Keep youself up to date.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pretty broad question. It will help if you have your code already organized as an MVC-style pattern so that you could reuse your work.

Both netbeans and eclipse are IDEs capable of creating a Java EE web app. Besides that, there are so much Java EE frameworks with very different approaches that it is quite hard to answer objectively (without writing a book :p).

You can still search for some popular Java EE frameworks like Spring, Vaadin, JSF or Struts.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I know all the concept of J2EE,just the problem is I cant able to design the form like I use to design it on Swing(drag n drop).here all component are coming in just single row one after another.Can you help me or guide how shall I design my Form in JSP.

Comment: If I understand,  you're having difficulties with the layout of your components. If so,  since the jsp files are rendered in html try having a look at html/css tutorials to properly layout your components. you can start with  [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp) at w3schools